# Data validation of all elements in wpf

Tags: wpf, validation

I have a window in WPF. I need to have a validation mechanizm to check all elements at once. If I use IDataErrorInfo there is only ability to validate one object at once in the indexer.

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        if (columnName == "Country"))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
                return "Country can't be empty";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I get all fields of my Window in the validation method?

Comment: the question is when you wanna check all "fields". and the answer is use the .Error Property when ever you wanna check all

Comment: So Country is public property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to declare a custom attribute and decorate the properties you wanna validate with it, and then use Reflection to iterate through those properties based on whether they have that custom attribute.